# Why does Oracle Service Bus deploy applications in AdminServer

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, osb

I am installing Oracle Service Bus 12.1.3 over a Fussion Middleware Infrastructure by following this installation guide.

I want to define a simple topology that consists of AdminServer server and a cluster compound by two managed servers (server1 and server2)

In the settings for AdminServer I did not specify any server group and for managed servers I choosed the server group OSB-MGD-SVRS-COMBINED as the guide states.

Once the installation ended and I run the AdminServer I realized that there a lot of applications, libraries and resource adapters deployed not just to the cluster but also to AdminServer.

I do not understand why Oracle Service Bus is deployed to AdminServer.

Comment: The Oracle Service Bus aggregates information about services (successful vs failed service calls, endpoints going offline, etc etc) so the admin server can display it. Read the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/administer/GUID-F42965DF-5AA2-4F8C-903D-A8C72101CD6C.htm#OSBAG462